# Postgres, Insert into many values with select

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

This is my first post here so please accept my apologies in advance if anything is out of place.

I have table "Users", for each user there is a statement about whether he participates in promotions "IsParticipates", this is one of the columns of the "Users" table and has a value of true or false.
I need to create new table "Stocks". It should contain the name of the promotion and the user ID.
There are several standard promotions for one user. But the user may refuse to participate in any or he may have an individual.

This is shortened version of my spreadsheet

```
  table : Users
+-------+-----------+---------------+
|   id  |   name    |IsParticipates |
+-------+-----------+---------------+
|   1   |   John    |     true      |
|   2   |   Mary    |     false     |
|   3   |   Jeff    |     true      |
|   4   |   Bill    |     false     |
|   5   |   Bob     |     false     |
+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

I want to get another table

```
  table : Stocks
+-------+--------------+---------+
|   id  |   name       |  userId |
+-------+--------------+---------+
|   1   |  StockName1  |     1   |
|   2   |  StockName2  |     1   |
|   3   |  StockName3  |     1   |
|   4   |  StockName4  |     1   |
|   5   |  StockName5  |     1   |
|   6   |  StockName6  |     1   |
|   7   |  StockName1  |     3   |
|   8   |  StockName2  |     3   |
|   9   |  StockName3  |     3   |
|  10   |  StockName4  |     3   |
|  11   |  StockName5  |     3   |
|  12   |  StockName6  |     3   |
+-------+--------------+---------+
```

Now I need to enter the default values. I tried:

```
INSERT INTO ""Stocks"" 
        (""Name"", ""UserId"")
      WITH
          u as (
              SELECT ""Id""
              FROM ""Users""
              WHERE ""IsParticipates""
          )
      VALUES
      ('StockName1', (SELECT ""Id"" FROM u)),
      ('StockName2', (SELECT ""Id"" FROM u)),
      ('StockName3', (SELECT ""Id"" FROM u)),
      ('StockName4', (SELECT ""Id"" FROM u)),
      ('StockName5', (SELECT ""Id"" FROM u)),
      ('StockName6', (SELECT ""Id"" FROM u));
```

But this only works if the user is one, but I have a lot of them.
I think this could be split into 6 requests since I have 6 stocks, but is this really necessary? Will you have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share sample data and expected output?

Comment: See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question with some data examples, table description and expected result all in text format

Comment: thank you very much, I edited my question, I hope it became clearer

Comment: @alyona I think there is some missing information. Aren't the StockName values stored somewhere or are just manual entries  ?

Comment: `INSERT INTO "Stocks" ("name", "userId")
SELECT 'StockName' || g, "id"
FROM "Users", generate_series(1, 6) g
WHERE "IsParticipates";` is this you need to achieve?

Comment: @ergest-basha
in this case it really should be just an input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the stocks table with a serial (autoincrement) id column:

```
create table stocks (id serial primary key, name varchar(20), userid int);
```

`INSERT` a `CROSS JOIN` of the stocknames and the IsParticipates true rows:

```
insert into stocks (name, userid)
select name, id
from
  (values ('StockName1'),
          ('StockName2'),
          ('StockName3'),
          ('StockName4'),
          ('StockName5'),
          ('StockName6')) v(name)
cross join (select id from users where IsParticipates is true) u;
```

Verify the result:

```
select * from stocks;
```

returns:

```
id  name    userid
1   StockName1  1
2   StockName2  1
3   StockName3  1
4   StockName4  1
5   StockName5  1
6   StockName6  1
7   StockName1  3
8   StockName2  3
9   StockName3  3
10  StockName4  3
11  StockName5  3
12  StockName6  3
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/tMHJEJvQ

However, I'd consider storing the different stock names in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Tables like below,

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255),
    IsParticipates boolean
);

CREATE TABLE Stocks (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255),
    userId integer
);
```

Replace `StockName` with actual ones

```
WITH TempStocks AS ( -- update values here ↓
    SELECT unnest(ARRAY['StockName1', 'StockName2', 'StockName3', 'StockName4', 'StockName5', 'StockName6']) AS stockName
)
INSERT INTO Stocks (name, userId)
SELECT ts.stockName, u.id
FROM Users u
CROSS JOIN TempStocks ts
WHERE u.IsParticipates;

select * from Stocks;
```

---

[***Demo***](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/efn3JHAi5UjVxQZkaunfzc/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `generate_series` along with `CROSS JOIN`

```
INSERT INTO Stocks (name, userId)
SELECT 'StockName' || s, u.id
FROM generate_series(1, 6) s
CROSS JOIN Users u
WHERE u.IsParticipates
ORDER BY u.id;
```

Then you can use `ORDER BY` to arrange the table as per your example.